# Turn my Curl into NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, request

I'm trying to imitate the effect of the following curl command in NodeJS, but can't quite seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

> curl https://url.com/rest/scripts -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN"

Assuming I already have the contents of **$TOKEN** stored in **var auth**, what would be the correct format for a request, synchronous or otherwise, for mimicking the above curl command?

My current attempt looks like this, but doesn't seem to work at all:

> var resData = request('GET', reqURL, auth);

EDIT: Solved, but I feel I should point out the above was using 'sync-request', hence how it was possible to store the result as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var request = require('request');
request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: reqURL,
  headers: 'Authorization: bearer ' + auth, //assuming var auth = $token
  json: true
 }, function(err, response, body){
    //Do whatever you want to here
});
```